# Arch: Recreate Swap Partition?

Tags: arch-linux, swap, zram

I'm running arch, installed with [archinstall](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/archinstall).

I read that arch uses [zram](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zram) for swapping, not disk. Also read somewhere that zram doesn't use disk for swap, so i don't need a swap partition. (I don't get why archinstall creates a swap partition if it's not needed)

Believing it wasn't needed, i deleted the swap partition (using cfdisk from the Live ISO).

Now arch won't boot. I'm getting a message about waiting 10 seconds for a partition, and then i get dropped into emergency shell.

```
Loading keymap.... Done. 
Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-partuuid/ecec0......[long number]
Error: Device /dev/disk/by-partuuid/ecec0......[long number] not found.
```

I attempted to recreate a swap partition in the same location on disk, using cfdisk, of "Linux Swap" type. Then i did mkswap on the reformatted swap partition.

`# mkswap /dev/sdb2`

But still not booting.

Do i need to change a partition ID in a grub config file?

I also attempted to mount the boot partition from the live ISO, and chroot into it, but that fails.

```
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
# arch-chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash No such file or directory. 
# chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command /usr/bin/zsh No such file or directory.
```

Comment: It's easier to change the UUID of your newly created swap partition to the original UUID of the deleted one.

Comment: @paladin I used gdisk to change the GUID on the swap part. Now on boot i'm getting `performing fsk on [new ID]... mounting [new ID] on real root... VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem... mount: /new_root: wrong fs type, bad option, or [etc]... failed to mount`